# Seamless JSON Data Import into Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm working on a project that requires me to import JSON data into Memgraph. What is the best approach to import JSON files into Memgraph? Are there any specific tools or procedures that I should be using to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use on of the two query modules that are implemented that are implemented in MAGE:

- [json_util](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/json-util) query module
- [import_util](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/import-util) query module

`json_util.load_from_path()` has no requirements about the formatting of data inside the JSON file. `import_util.json()` procedure requires data to be formatted in a specific way. `export_util.json()` procedure generates the same format when it's used to export data from Memgraph into the JSON file.